# make clean && make mrproper not working

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, android-ndk, fedora

I'm working off a tutorial to build an Android Kernel using fedora 22 terminal.

These are the steps I have done

1. `sudo dnf install gcc ncurses-devel`
2. downloaded Android ndk
3. ./android-ndk.bin
4. cd Android-Kernel into the folder where my phone kernel and Any-Kernel-master.zip is
5. tar the phone kernel renamed it bliss
6. `ln -s bliss linux`
7. export CROSS COMPILE=/home/amber/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
8. `make clean && make mrproper`

When I do the last step I get

> make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in trying to get this to work?

Comment: There is either no *Makefile* or no target `clean` there.

Comment: @Ajoy2w The Android source tree has its own build scripts for building the kernel.